# How can we extract video URL from xml response

Tags: xml

I am building a app in which i need to call a 3rd party api to play video directly on RHC box.
the party provided a url which is when it hit on url gives XML response.
how can i extract the video url from xml response.
Url :
http://something/math11072016part2.smil/jwplayer.smil

this type of Required URL :http://something/97760.mp4

Answer (score 0):

By applying the following `xpath` expression on the received XML, you'll get a list of `video` nodes:

```
smil/body/switch/video
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you please share an example from my url. it would be of great help for understanding

Comment: What is the technology used for parsing the XML document?